# PHP Generate possible number with specific format

Tags: php, algorithm

I need to generate possible number with some format/rule.

1. 5 digit number
2. first digit > 0

   for($x=0;$x=10;$x++) {
   $first=1;$second=0;$third=0;$fourth=0;$five=0;

   for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
       $first=$i; break;
   }
   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
       $second=$i; break;
   }
   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
       $third=$i; break;
   }
   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
       $fourth=$i; break;
   }
   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
       $five=$i; break;
   }

   echo $first.$second.$third.$fourth.$five.'\n';
   }

desired result:
10000
10001
10002
...until
99999

but seems broken :(

Comment: You are currently assign the same valut to 2,3,4,5 so the result would be , 11111 12222 13333 14444......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using separate `for` loops you need to [nest](https://www.google.com/search?q=nested+for+loops+php) them inside one another:

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j <= 9; $j++){
        for($k = 0; $k <= 9; $k++){
            for($l = 0; $l <= 9; $l++){
                for($m = 0; $m <= 9; $m++){
                    print("$i$j$k$l$m\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RkzIO9)

But, obviously, a simpler approach would employ only one `for` loop:

```
for($i = 10000; $i <= 99999; $i++){
    print("$i\n");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VX5xn0)

Comment: Or simply `echo implode("\n",range(10000,99999));` but whats the point lol ;p

Comment: OMG.. you right for simpler version. 
but actually i need to prevent specific number to shown. ex: number 6 will never shown, that's why i m thinking multiple loops

Thank you